# Docker Volumen compartir carpeta vs volumen

Tags: docker

> Esta pregunta es mas teórica.

**¿Cual seria la diferencia entre compartir carpeta o usar volumen en docker?** cual seria la ventaja entro un caso u otro

**Compartir carpeta:**

- `docker run -v /home/user/miweb:/var/www/html`

**Usando volumen:**

- creamos un volumen: `docker volume create  mi-volumen`
- usamos el volumen: `docker run -v mi-volumen:/var/www/html`

Comment: Los "named volumes" son independientes del host. Sin embargo la primera forma, si corres ese comando en otra máquina es probable que la carpeta no existan en esa otra máquina.

Answer (score 3):

Este es un tema muy interesante que engloba mucha teoría, primero que nada vamos a definir que estos dos mecanismo `Docker Volumes` y `mounted files` o carpetas compartidas como tu le llamas, sirven para **Guardar informacón de forma persistente** de manera que **aún eliminando el contenedor** la información quedará guardada de forma independiente.

¿Cual es su diferencia?

**Mounted Files**

```sh
docker run -it -v /path/absoluto/a/mydata/:/mydata:z busybox
```

- Son fáciles de identficar porque inician con la ruta absoluta que se desea compartir de tu computadora(inician con `/`).
- Los datos residen en tu computadora.
- Si cambias de computadora debes mover tus datos a la otra computadora
- Si quieres hacer un backup debes hacerlo sin ayuda de docker
- No esta diseñado para compartirse entre contenedores.
- Es muy útil para entornos de desarrollo, ya que si modificamos el contenido en nuestra computadora automaticamente se modifica en el contenedor y viseversa.
- El último argumento `z` configura los permisos correctamente en Sistemas que tienen el SELinux por lo que siempre es recomendado definirlo.

**Docker Volumes**

```sh
docker run -it -v mydata:/mydata:z busybox
```

- Son fáciles de identificar porque inician con el nombre del volumen (notese que no lleva `/`)
- Los datos residen en Docker si estas desplegando docker en la nube tus datos estarán en la arquitectura en la nube.
- Si cambias de computadora "no importa" el volumen esta en la nube y no tendrás problemas.
- Es más recomendado para entornos de producción.
- Puedes compartir los volumenes entre contenedores.
- No hay problemas de permisos relacionados con el SELinux.

Cabe destacar que existe una sintaxis mucho más explicta utilizando la opción `--mount` no necesitan practicamente explicación:

```sh
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/path/absoluto/a/mydata,target=/mydata busybox
docker run -it --mount type=volume,source=mydata,target=/mydata busybox
```

Debes tomar en cuenta que no hay forma de re-etiquetar el contexto de los archivos con `z` si se utiliza la opción `--mount` por lo que si la necesitas deberás utilizar `-v`

Más información [Casos de uso](https://serverfault.com/questions/996785/docker-volumes-vs-mount-binds-what-are-the-use-cases), [Docker Volumes vs Mounted Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357252/docker-data-volume-vs-mounted-host-directory).

Espero te ayude.